# How can we override standard button on standard objects like Contact with a Flow

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I am trying to launch a flow  from the  standard  new button on the contact,
I know we could override standard buttons with Visualforce and lightning components but is there any way to override to launch a flow

Comment: Flows have URLs and they can be used in custom URL buttons; you can even pass merge field params

Answer (score 2):

By Default, You can override the lightning Interface button with Vf Page and Lightning Component.  If you have flow and want to override the button with a flow:-

1. You can create a [lightning component](https://unofficialsf.com/how-to-launch-flows-from-your-own-lightning-web-component/) where you do call your flow on load.
2. You can create a new custom button on contact record using flow.
3. Or you can create a [url button that launches flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_distribute_internal_url.htm&type=5)

[image]

[image]